# KEIL : Hex file is not getting generated

Tags: arm, keil

I have the 'Create Hex File' options enabled for the target project in KEIL uVIsion. But still I am not able to see the generated Hex project file?

Is there any other config updation that we need to do in KEIL?

Comment: It should be there somewhere! Search your disk for *.hex files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check All the settings in **"Option for Target"** from keil ID as
Step 1: Select folder for objects.
Step 2: Set Name of Executable.
Step 3: checked create executable button.
Step 4: checked Create HEX file .
Step 5: Select HEX file format from combo box like HEX-386 or HEX-80.
Step 6: OK and build.

Comment: Yes, I had already done these steps - turned out to be some virus issue - ran antivirus and after that the issue got resolved. That's why I prefer Linux OS - working on windows is a great headache .. sorry but true ..